# How to echo a dynamic url

Tags: urls

I need to insert following dynamic URL:

```
echo $myfy->get_retrieve_cart_url( $post->ID, $landing_page )
```

into:

```
echo "<a href='"LINK"'> . get_title() . </a>";
```

Basically, I need to replace the "LINK" with above URL, I have tried all combinations that I've thought about and I'm getting a string error, Can anybody give me a helpline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two workarounds:

**If the first line you're mentioning is inside a void function:**

You have to create a wrapper function and use `ob_` functions to get the real link:

```
<?php
function echo_link($post, $landing_page) {
    global $myfy;
    echo $myfy->get_retrieve_cart_url( $post->ID, $landing_page );
}
function get_link($post, $landing_page){
    ob_start();
    echo_link($post, $landing_page);
    return ob_get_clean();
}

// And finally in your result:
echo "a href='" . get_link($post, $landing_page) . "'>.get_title()";
```

**If the first line you're mentioning is not inside a void function or you can simply duplicate it without concerning about the future changes:**

```
<?php
$link = $myfy->get_retrieve_cart_url( $post->ID, $landing_page );
echo "a href='" . $link . "'>.get_title()";
```

By the way, You might forget about those dots (`.`) while trying to concatenate your strings.

Comment: I was able insert the link but url is not resolved correct, this goes as a part of a custom post query in woocommerce plugin.

Comment: Double check your call and give more information about your plugin or at least the source code of `get_retrieve_cart_url` function.

Comment: I already have page template which load the cart successfully with this above url under custom post types, so though to do a plugin for same purpose. This url load inside a query. I'll do test your code and share the updated code for more insight.

Comment: I was able to get the correct path by adding $post to your 1st function (global $myfy, $post;) Thanks mate for support.